# How can i get the day month and year from my datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

this is my aspx code for my calendar:

```
<script src="jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="jQuery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        $.datepicker.regional['he'] = {
            closeText: 'סגור',
            prevText: '&#x3c;הקודם',
            nextText: 'הבא&#x3e;',
            currentText: 'היום',
            monthNames: ['ינואר', 'פברואר', 'מרץ', 'אפריל', 'מאי', 'יוני',
            'יולי', 'אוגוסט', 'ספטמבר', 'אוקטובר', 'נובמבר', 'דצמבר'],
            monthNamesShort: ['ינו', 'פבר', 'מרץ', 'אפר', 'מאי', 'יוני',
            'יולי', 'אוג', 'ספט', 'אוק', 'נוב', 'דצמ'],
            dayNames: ['ראשון', 'שני', 'שלישי', 'רביעי', 'חמישי', 'שישי', 'שבת'],
            dayNamesShort: ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ש'],
            dayNamesMin: ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ש'],
            weekHeader: 'Wk',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 0,
            isRTL: true,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['he']);
        jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker();


        **var day = jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>")('getDate').getDate();
        var month =jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>")('getDate').getMonth();
        var year =  jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>")('getDate').getYear();
        alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);**

    });

</script>
```

I want to get the day, month and year from my calendar- what am i doing wrong in these 3 rows? how can i separate it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What happens with the alert?

Comment: ...is there an error?

Comment: is there a date even set at the time you run this code?

Comment: no there isn't a date set

Comment: Check for errors at your browser Console - I suggest using [Firebug for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) (if you're not using it yet).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `.datepicker` when calling the `getDate()` method on your Datepicker.

```
var day = jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker('getDate').getDate();
var month =jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker('getDate').getMonth();
var year =  jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker('getDate').getYear();
alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
```

Or more concisely, and using `getFullYear()` plus detecting a `null` date:

```
var myDate = jQuery("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker('getDate');
var myAlert = (!myDate)? "no date set" : myDate.getDate() + '-' + myDate.getMonth() + '-' + myDate.getFullYear();
alert(myAlert);
```

See it working in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGZcu/1/).

Comment: @user3082812 make sure that `datepicker.ClientID` is set then, I included a link to a working implementation here http://jsfiddle.net/MGZcu/1/

Comment: do i have to put a button to see the alert?

Comment: no, but you something has to trigger it. if you just do it on page load then there won't be a date set in your datepicker, so the date will be null.

Comment: after i get the date separately- how can i use the id of the date in my c# code?

Comment: that's an entirely different question... it looks like you have it in `<%=datepicker.ClientID%>` though.